# 開発環境でもアセットファイル名にフィンガープリントが付与されるなどでうまく表示できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

追記：
すみません。お恥ずかしいのですが、アセット周りを試し終えた結果、根本的にHTMLにミスがあることに気づきました。

---

**app/assets/images/hoge.png**を置きました。

拡張子が`.css.scss`のファイルに、

```
background-image: image-url('hoge.png');
```

と記述し、ChromeのDeveloper Toolsで確認したところ

```
background-image: url(/assets/hoge-5c6df45c1cb3ef12bc11fb1dae8261db9737b142d46985f6a44ed1c0fbd62831.png);
```

と **/assets/hoge-フィンガープリント.png**という形になっており
フィンガープリントが付与されたファイル名の画像がそもそもないので取得できないのかと思いましたが、本来欲しいのは、**app/assets/images/** ディレクトリなので**images/** が足りないと思い、

```
background-image: image-url('images/hoge.png');
```

と書き換えたところ、今度はフィンガープリントが付与されず、加えて、**images/** が2つも入ってしまいました。

```
background-image: url(/images/images/hoge.png);
```

仕方がないので、**app/assets/hoge.png**にも同様にファイルを置いてみましたが、同様に表示されません。

そもそも`.css.scss`ファイルもDeveloper Toolsで確認したところフィンガープリントが付与されたCSSファイルに変換されているようで、変換されたものをlinkタグでアクセスしにいっているようです(このCSSファイルはうまく読み込めている模様。なぜなら`background-color`を試しに指定したとき色はついたので)。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="foobar.self-3ca83820f3dd876e282a5295e5e27e4de51ac6a62b5bb8812844fbef484ca67f.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

正しいscssの書き方を教えて下さい。

---

追記：

**development.rb**を

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = false
```

にしたところ、CSSやJSファイルへのダイジェストの付与はなくなりましたが、以前として、
`background-image: url(/assets/hoge-ダイジェスト)`
の状態でした。

**development.rb**を

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.digest = false
```

にすると、今まで**app/assets/stylesheets**配下に置いていた`css.scss`ファイルが勝手にCSSへ変換され、その変換されたファイルへのlinkタグが自動でERBに挿入されていましたのですが、linkタグが生成されなくなり、そもそもCSSへアクセスできなくなりました。

Answer (score 1):

development 環境で `ダイジェストをオフにする` を試してみてください

[アセットパイプライン | Rails ガイド](http://railsguides.jp/asset_pipeline.html#%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E3%82%AA%E3%83%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: CSSやJSファイル名へのダイジェストは消えましたが、依然として`background-image: url(/assets/hoge-ダイジェスト)`　と画像ファイル名はダイジェストが付与されています。

Comment: config.assets.debugとconfig.assets.digestの2つがあったんですね。両方試してみた結果を追記しました。